# How to create service in vue js with node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, vue.js, service

I am trying to create my first app in vue with node js using sql. I made service to write my post and get functions in vue js it working fine in getting and posting data but when i use parameterized url it attached client base url with end point i provide in service.

Vue route is: http://localhost:8080/update-category/1
and node api is http://localhost:3001/api/category/update-category

[error showed in picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZAQb.png)

Comment: Can you provide more information about the request?

Comment: route: 
 {path: '/update-category/:id', component : Category},

Service: 
const url = 'api/category/';

static updateCategory(categoryData) {
        console.log("category", categoryData)
        return axios.post(`${url}${'update-category'}`, {
            categoryData
        });
         
Component: 
await CategoryService.updateCategory({
              catID : this.id,
              catName: this.categoryName,
              catDesc : this.catDesc,
              date: this.date
          })

Comment: server side api function: 
db.query(sql, [catName, catDesc, catID  ],  function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (!err){
                        res.send('Updated');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                });

Comment: I mean, can you edit your question to include more information about the request? I could not get a clear picture of whats happening with your code

Comment: anyway, this seems more like a problem with your axios configuration than anything else